# How to parse string to double with out scientific notation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-7

I want to parse string to double but with scientific notation. Please provide ant solution for solving this problem.

```
    String str="123434344";
    Double db=Double.parseDouble(str);
    System.out.println("Value:"+db);
```

This is my output:
           Value:1.23434344E8
but i want to this double like this: 123434344.00

How it is possible please provide me solution for this. Thanks a lot.!!

Comment: You could use `DecimalFormat` for this.

Comment: You can use `DecimalFormat` for this

Comment: Your problem isn't parsing, it is formatting

Answer (score 2):

```
String str="123434344";
Double db=Double.parseDouble(str);
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
System.out.println("Value:"+format.format(db));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
Double d = Double.parseDouble("123434344");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

The output will be :

```
123434344.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("Value: %0.2f%n", db);
```

Print formated, Where `%n` stands for newline.